# Way to check whether TinyMCE is active in WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce

I'm working on a plugin that, when TinyMCE is in use as the Visual editor, uses TinyMCE commands to insert text into body content editing area. Currently, it works by just running the command. If it works, then TinyMCE is active and if not, then I have custom JS for working with the HTML editor.

My question, however: is there any way to check whether TinyMCE is active or not instead of just running the command and having it fail when it isn't?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

And... I've answered the question for myself. The conditional you want to test for is as follows:

```
is_tinyMCE_active = false;
if (typeof(tinyMCE) != "undefined") {
  if (tinyMCE.activeEditor == null || tinyMCE.activeEditor.isHidden() != false) {
    is_tinyMCE_active = true;
  }
}
```

The trick is that `tinyMCE.activeEditor` returns null when TinyMCE isn't activated. You can use the `isHidden()` method to make sure it isn't executing when you've switched back to HTML editor mode.

This is poorly documented on the TinyMCE website and forums.

Comment: Hm this isn't working for me. For some reason, it's true regardless of whether its in HTML mode or Visual mode. Anyone else having this issue?

Comment: I think my issue is that the tinyMCE editor has not loaded and I am checking before its fully loaded. How do I wait until its loaded before I do this check?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, I saw that code on wordpress: ABSPATH/wp-includes/js/autosave.js file

```
// (bool) is rich editor enabled and active
var rich = (typeof tinyMCE != "undefined") && tinyMCE.activeEditor && !tinyMCE.activeEditor.isHidden();
```

Answer (score 2):

As this questions ranked in search engines. I think I should extend Daniels answers a little bit to support when we have multiple instances of wordpress editor in a single page.

```
    var is_editor_active = function(editor_id){

        if(typeof tinyMCE == 'undefined'){
            return false;
        }

        if( typeof editor_id == 'undefined' ){
            editor = tinyMCE.activeEditor;
        }else{
            editor = tinyMCE.EditorManager.get(editor_id);
        }

        if(editor == null){
            return false;
        }

         return !editor.isHidden();

    };
```

**Uses**

When you only need to check the active editor

```
if(is_editor_active()){
    // do stuff
}
```

If an editor with certain id needed to be checked

```
if(is_editor_active('mycontent'){
    // do stuff
}
```

I hope this little function will be helpful to others :)

Answer (score 0):

According to WordPress editor.js we can easily check that :

```
    if ( window.wpActiveEditor ) {
       // editor active
    }else {
       // not active
    }
```